# rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm running indigo on a RPi.

I have a script to use a joystick to run a servo, which I'll paste below. I know the code subscribing to this is working, because when I publish angles to it using rostopic, the servo turns. I was hoping that when I use this script, I could push the joystick up, and the servo would turn more positive. I based my usage of the joy node on [this link](http://andrewdai.co/xbox-controller-ros.html#rosjoy) from the ROS Wiki page. I got the following error.

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1425312842.009290] bad callback: <function joy_talker at 0x224c1b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 702, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/servo/joy.py", line 8, in joy_talker
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 274, in init_node
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSException("rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments: "+str(_init_node_args))
ROSException: rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments: ('servo_joy', ['/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/servo/joy.py'], False, None, False, False)
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

def joy_talker(msg):
        pub = rospy.Publisher('angle', Float32, queue_size=10)
        rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                rospy.logdebug("Joy Recieved: [Vx:%f, Wz:%f]"%(msg.axes[1],msg.$
                angle  = msg.axes[1]  * 180
                rospy.loginfo(angle)
        pub.publish(angle)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('servo_joy')

        rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, joy_talker)

        rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204067/rospy.init_node()-has-already-been-called-with-different-arguments/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Move all initialisation of publishers / subscribers out of your `joy_talker` callback. Only publish messages inside callbacks, never (well .. never ..) create anything related to message publication and / or subscription in them. Also: no node initialisation statements inside callbacks.

Callbacks are called upon reception of a message, a *single* message. How do you expect the code you posted to work? Upon reception of the first `Joy` msg, your callback will be invoked, which (ignoring the call to `rospy.init_node(..)` for now) then enters an (potentially) infinite while-loop. `pub.publish(..)` will never be invoked.

---

Edit: if you based your code on the example from the link you posted, where did the extra while-loop and node initialisation come from? As you can see in the xbox example, the msg callback only performs some very simple calculations, before publishing a new message.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2015-03-04**:
OK. After looking at it again I realized it was a garbage code. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-04**:
No problem. Re-reading my answer it seems a bit harsh, hope you didn't take it personal.

**Comment by [freedom696](https://answers.ros.org/users/32392/freedom696/) on 2017-10-25**:
hi!
I have encounter the same error， but the error was occured when i initialise multiple ros node. do you know how to resolve this problem?
thanks!
best wishes from China~

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-26**:
You cannot call `rospy.init_node` more than once in a python program.

**Comment by [freedom696](https://answers.ros.org/users/32392/freedom696/) on 2017-10-26**:
yeah!I just realized that a moment ago！
thank you all the same.

**Comment by [rajk97](https://answers.ros.org/users/52450/rajk97/) on 2020-06-28**:
Is it not possible even after giving the command  `rospy.signal_shutdown("Shutdown node")` to shutdown the node inside python function to start another node?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-29**:
No, it's not supported -- at least last time I checked.

Some resources are not completely released, causing `rospy.init_node(..)` to error out when attempting to call it twice.

But do please check, as `rospy` has seen quite some fixes since the last time this was discussed in this question.

**Comment by [sea-bass](https://answers.ros.org/users/40466/sea-bass/) on 2021-01-26**:
It's still not supported (at least in Melodic). Normally I only would need 1 node, but when running unit tests using `pytest` it seems to treat all of my separate test files as 1 process and blocks me from starting multiple nodes. Bummer :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-27**:
No, and I don't expect this to ever become supported in ROS 1.

In ROS 1: one process == one node.